# Pandas Data Frame, find max value and return adjacent column value, not the entire row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

New to Pandas so I'm sorry if there is an obvious solution...
I imported a CSV that only had 2 columns and I created a 3rd column.
Here's a screen shot of the top 10 rows and header:
[Screen shot of DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJhjP.png)

I've figured out how to find the min and max values in the ['Amount Changed'] column but also need to pull the date associated with the min and max - but not the index and ['Profit/Loss']. I've tried iloc, loc, read about groupby - I can't get any of them to return a single value (in this case a date) that I can use again.

My goal is to create a new variable 'Gi_Date' that is in the same row as the max value in ['Amount Changed'] but tied to the date in the ['Date'] column.

I'm trying to keep the variables separate so I can use them in print statements, write them to txt files, etc.

```
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#path for CSV file
csvpath = ("budget_data.csv")
#Read CSV into Panadas and give it a variable name Bank_pd
Bank_pd = pd.read_csv(csvpath, parse_dates=True)

#Number of month records in the CSV
Months = Bank_pd["Date"].count()

#Total amount of money captured in the data converted to currency
Total_Funds = '${:.0f}'.format(Bank_pd["Profit/Losses"].sum())

#Determine the amount of increase or decrease from the previous month
AmtChange = Bank_pd["Profit/Losses"].diff()
Bank_pd["Amount Changed"] = AmtChange

#Identify the greatest positive change
GreatestIncrease = '${:.0f}'.format(Bank_pd["Amount Changed"].max())
Gi_Date = Bank_pd[Bank_pd["Date"] == GreatestIncrease]

#Identify the greatest negative change
GreatestDecrease =  '${:.0f}'.format(Bank_pd["Amount Changed"].min())
Gd_Date = Bank_pd[Bank_pd['Date'] == GreatestDecrease]

print(f"Total Months: {Months}")
print(f"Total: {Total_Funds}")
print(f"Greatest Increase in Profits: {Gi_Date}  ({GreatestIncrease})")
print(f"Greatest Decrease in Profits: {Gd_Date} ({GreatestDecrease})")
```

When I run the script in git bash I don't get an error anymore so I think I'm getting close, rather than showing the date it says:

```
$ python PyBank.py
Total Months: 86
Total: $38382578
Greatest Increase in Profits: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Profit/Losses, Amount Changed]
Index: []  ($1926159)
Greatest Decrease in Profits: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date, Profit/Losses, Amount Changed]
Index: [] ($-2196167)
```

I want it to print out like this:

```
$ python PyBank.py
Total Months: 86
Total: $38382578
Greatest Increase in Profits: Feb-2012  ($1926159)
Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sept-2013 ($-2196167)
```

Here is one years worth of the original DataFrame:

```
bank_pd = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['Jan-10', 'Feb-10', 'Mar-10', 'Apl-10', 'May-10', 'Jun-10', 'Jul-10', 'Aug-10', 'Sep-10', 'Oct-10', 'Nov-10', 'Dec-10'],
                        'Profit/Losses':[867884, 984655, 322013, -69417, 310503, 522857, 1033096, 604885, -216386, 477532, 893810, -80353]})
```

The expected output with the sample df would be:
Total Months: 12
Total Funds: $5651079
Greatest Increase in Profits: Oct-10 ($693918)
Greatest Decrease in Profits: Dec-10 ($-974163)

I also had an error in the sample dataframe from above, I was missing a month when I typed it out quickly - it's fixed now.

Thanks!

Comment: please post your current dataframe and your expected output dataframe

Comment: @pyd - here is a sample of the dataframe I'm using. I didn't post an expected outcome dataframe because what I'm really after is how to identify a values from the dataframe that I can use elsewhere, i.e. print to a txt file... Thanks!

Comment: cant you just do `df.sort_values('Profit/Losses').tail(1).Date` for maximum date and change tail to `head` from minimum date??

Comment: @Dave please, give us expected output for given subset of your data

Comment: @Dave you can just fetch out the values of dates rather than putting back them in dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm seeing few glitches in the variables used.

```
Bank_pd["Amount Changed"] = AmtChange
```

The above statement is actually replacing the dataframe with column "Amount Changed". After this statement you can use this column for any manipulation.

Below is the updated code and highlighted the newly added lines. You could add further formatting:

```
import pandas as pd


csvpath = ("budget_data.csv")

Bank_pd = pd.read_csv(csvpath, parse_dates=True)
inp_bank_pd = pd.DataFrame(Bank_pd)

Months = Bank_pd["Date"].count()
Total_Funds = '${:.0f}'.format(Bank_pd["Profit/Losses"].sum())

AmtChange = Bank_pd["Profit/Losses"].diff()
GreatestIncrease = Bank_pd["Amount Changed"].max()

Gi_Date = inp_bank_pd.loc[Bank_pd["Amount Changed"] == GreatestIncrease]

print(Months)
print(Total_Funds)
print(Gi_Date['Date'].values[0])
print(GreatestIncrease)
```

Comment: Vijay - thanks for the suggestion! I keep getting an Index Error: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size of 0. I'll keep playing with it though, I need to get comfortable with the loc functions!

Comment: It took me a while to get this to work, and for some reason the only way I could get it to work is with the Bank_pd["Amount Changed"] = AmtChange. From what I can tell that line adds a new column to the df and runs the AmtChange formula in each of the rows. Thanks - greatly appreciate the help @Nihal and Vijay!!

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, Gi_date and Gd_date are trying to initialize new DF's instead of calling values. Change Gi_Date and Gd_Date:

```
Gi_Date = Bank_pd.sort_values('Profit/Losses').tail(1).Date
Gd_Date = Bank_pd.sort_values('Profit/Losses').head(1).Date
```

Check outputs:

```
Gi_Date
Jul-10
Gd_Date
Sep-10
```

To print how you want to print using string formatting:

```
print("Total Months: %s" %(Months))
print("Total: %s" %(Total_Funds))
print("Greatest Increase in Profits: %s %s" %(Gi_Date.to_string(index=False), GreatestIncrease))
print("Greatest Decrease in Profits: %s %s" %(Gd_Date.to_string(index=False), GreatestDecrease))
```

Note if you don't use the:

```
(Gd_Date.to_string(index=False)
```

The pandas object information will be included in the print output, like it is in your example when you see the DataFrame info.
Output for 12 month sample DF:

```
Total Months: 12
Total: $5651079
Greatest Increase in Profits: Jul-10 $693918
Greatest Decrease in Profits: Sep-10 $-974163
```

Comment: This got me really close! Thanks! I made a few small changes and still have one small bug. I'm matching the values to the ('Amount Changed') min and max, and as a result the first month (Jan-10) doesn't have a value in that column. I then changed the gd...head(2) to skip January and got it to print out Oct-10, which is what I was expecting. The weird thing now is that it is printing out Oct-10 Jan-10 $693918. I just need to figure out how to get rid of the Jan-10 and it's perfect!

Comment: head() isn't doing what you think. It is referring to the number of values to select, not the location of the values. Head() also isn't 0 based because head(1) selects the first row. head(2) selects the first 2 rows, etc. If you would like me to take a look at it later today I would be happy to do so! If you are happy with the accepted answer I will let it be.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and offer to help. The other two solutions worked for me so you don't need to spend any more time on this one. I am curious about how head and tail work, and if there is a way to skip X rows for future reference... Thanks!-dk

Answer (score 1):

Use `Series.idxmin` and `Series.idxmax` with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Amount Changed'].idxmin(), 'Date']
df.loc[df['Amount Changed'].idxmax(), 'Date']
```

Full example based on your sample DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['Jan-2010', 'Feb-2010', 'Mar-2010', 'Apr-2010', 'May-2010',
                           'Jun-2010', 'Jul-2010', 'Aug-2010', 'Sep-2010', 'Oct-2010'],
                   'Profit/Losses': [867884,984655,322013,-69417,310503,522857,
                                     1033096,604885,-216386,477532]})
df['Amount Changed'] = df['Profit/Losses'].diff()

print(df)

       Date  Profit/Losses  Amount Changed
0  Jan-2010         867884             NaN
1  Feb-2010         984655        116771.0
2  Mar-2010         322013       -662642.0
3  Apr-2010         -69417       -391430.0
4  May-2010         310503        379920.0
5  Jun-2010         522857        212354.0
6  Jul-2010        1033096        510239.0
7  Aug-2010         604885       -428211.0
8  Sep-2010        -216386       -821271.0
9  Oct-2010         477532        693918.0

print(df.loc[df['Amount Changed'].idxmin(), 'Date'])
print(df.loc[df['Amount Changed'].idxmax(), 'Date'])

Sep-2010
Oct-2010
```

Comment: This worked too! I really appreciate an idxmax with loc example!